# PhoneGap error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined"

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying use the menu button on Android, with the PhoneGap. The problem is that I can't use it because appear this error on log:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined".

This is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>-->
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>-->
            <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function onLoad() {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                        document.addEventListener("menubutton", function(){
                            alert('Menu button pressed.');    
                        }, true);
                    }, false);
                }
            </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
            <p>Hello world!</p>
        </body>
</html>
```

I thought that the problem was the import of cordova.js, so I tried use all this options that were commented.

I don't know if have any relation, but all the times I start the script, appear this error in the console, with the red color:

```
E/webview(21743): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
E/webview(21743): registerForStylusPenEvent START
E/webview(21743): registerForStylusPenEvent END
```

I'm sorry if had some english error, but I'm trying do it without the Google Translator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First please check that the path and file name to your cordova.js are correct. Then remove the onLoad event and write the `deviceready` event hook in the script file as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", function() {
          alert('Menu button pressed.');
        }, true);
      }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a stupid error. The place where I read said that the file cordova-x-x-x.js was added automatically...
After you answered, I put the file in the folder and it worked.

Comment: @WhizKid i added that cordova.js file properly. but after that it is not working

Comment: @DeepikaLalra can you post your code as a separate question and post the link here?

Comment: @Whizkid747 it is working fine. The mistake was i am not registering deviceready event properly. I was writing document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false); The Mistake was i am attaching "()" after callback function.