# backbutton in phonegap not getting registered and not working properly

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegapand i am registering backbutton `onDeviceReady` Function but getting function called when clicked on device's back button. and i have added

```
<script src="lib/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>

document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackClickEvent, false);

function onBackClickEvent() {
    alert("back onBackClickEvent");     
}
```

This `onBackClickEvent()` function is not getting called, I've never seen that alert poped up. I am also getting an error of Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

what could be the error Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer to my Question. I was struggling and many developers tries to resolve it and when i found the silly mistake i found myself so silly.

I was writing

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```

instead of

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

thats why i am getting an error cordova is not defined and no other listeners are getting registered.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to call the "**deviceready**" event.

From phonegap doc :

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should
>   use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web
>   application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function
>   before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded.
>   After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova
>   function.

Try this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackClickEvent, false);
}

function onBackClickEvent()
{
    alert("back onBackClickEvent");     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this bug after upgrading to cordova 3.1. Turns out that this has to be explicitly added in config.xml phonegap 3.* onwards.

```
<feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
```

See this [link](http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/icenium-general-discussion/any-known-issues-with-backbutton-event-with-cordova-3-0-project#8Usgc41hT0--o7srDw6OQg)

Answer (score 3):

For the back button I use this

```
//Android back button handler methods
$(document).ready(function()
{
document.addEventListener("deviceready", setOverrideBackbutton, false);
});

/**
* Allow override of the back button on Android platforms
*/
function setOverrideBackbutton()
{
if (typeof device != "undefined" && device.platform == "Android")
{
    navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(true);
}
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonTap, true);
}

/**
 * Callback after a backbutton tap on Android and windows platforms.
 * Do nothing.
 */
function backButtonTap()
{
//Do not remove
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pls check that the path and file name to your cordova.js is correct.
make sure you have checked true cordova.jar file and Android private libs in project property-> Java Build Path-> Order & Export.

For more infomation check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149986/phonegap-error-uncaught-referenceerror-cordova-is-not-defined)

and if you import more than one files then put the cordova.js file before the other.js file and it should work.

and Just use

```
<script src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
```

instead of

and also check this [link1](https://gist.github.com/macdonst/955496) & [link2](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)